# How to display an image with any file format in a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, file-extension

I have this code which accepts only those images with `.bmp` format

```
String format="";
if(pic_sel_file.toLowerCase().endsWith(".bmp"))
    format="BMP";
```

How to change this code so that it can accept images with any file format(.jpg,.tif,etc)?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having multiple *if-then-else* statements, you could use use a regular expression to do a match on a list of file extension types. `endsWith` does not take a regex, so you could do:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|tif)$").matcher(pic_sel_file);
if (m.matches()) {
   format = m.group(1).toUpperCase();
}
```

- `(?i)` Ignore case
- `\\.` Escaped dot character
- `(bmp|...` Image types
- `$` End of line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid regexp, you can use a collection and loop over it:

```
List<String> allowedFileEndings = Arrays.asList("bmp", "png", "gif"); //or array
for (String allowedFileEndingsItem : allowedFileEndings) {
    if(pic_sel_file.toLowerCase().endsWith(allowedFileEndingsItem)) // or "." + allowedFileEndingsItem
    {
        format = allowedFileEndingsItem; // uppercase if you want
        break;
    }
}
```

I would even consider using a enum for the file formats, this could make life easier for the format handling.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this entire task would be better suited to a [`JFileChooser` with a filter for supported image types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13521592/418556).

[image]

#### Related

- [`ListImageReaders`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544777/418556)
- [TIFF support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11517879/418556)